# BI Publisher BASE64 output generation error

Tags: web-services, soapui, bi-publisher

I have created a BI Publisher report which  file type is XML. Than I want to create base64 output via SOAP UI.

And service that I have been calling "PublicReportService?wsdl".
Firstly I run "getreportDefination" method and it ended without any error after that I tried to run "runreport" but I get this following error msg from SOAP UI;

```
<faultstring>oracle.xdo.webservice.exception.OperationFailedException: PublicReportService::generateReport failed: due to File type not supported: ?</faultstring>
```

What causes this problem?

And what should I do?

BI Publisher Version
Oracle BI Publisher 11.1.1.7.150120

SOAP UI Version
4.0.1

Comment: Error message is clear - `File type not supported`

Comment: I passed this step but now it can not generate reportbytes .